NPM is not building
Any time I call npm run build I get this error
[09:52:47] [snowpack] ! building files...
[09:52:48] [snowpack] Not Found (/static/Ethiopia&)
[09:52:48] [snowpack] Error: Not Found (/static/Ethiopia&)
    at Object.loadUrl (C:\Users\cjlyn\PycharmProjects\untitled2\node_modules\snowpack\lib\cjs\commands\dev.js:570:23)
    at flushFileQueue (C:\Users\cjlyn\PycharmProjects\untitled2\node_modules\snowpack\lib\cjs\build\process.js:191:40)
    at async Object.buildFiles (C:\Users\cjlyn\PycharmProjects\untitled2\node_modules\snowpack\lib\cjs\build\process.js:226:5)
    at async build (C:\Users\cjlyn\PycharmProjects\untitled2\node_modules\snowpack\lib\cjs\commands\build.js:11:5)
    at async Object.command (C:\Users\cjlyn\PycharmProjects\untitled2\node_modules\snowpack\lib\cjs\commands\build.js:35:9)
    at async cli (C:\Users\cjlyn\PycharmProjects\untitled2\node_modules\snowpack\lib\cjs\index.js:174:9)

This is my snowpack.config.mjs file
export default {
  mount: {
    public: { url: '/', static: true },
    src: { url: '/dist' },
  },
  plugins: [
    [
      '@snowpack/plugin-typescript',
      {
        /* Yarn PnP workaround: see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@snowpack/plugin-typescript */
        ...(process.versions.pnp ? { tsc: 'yarn pnpify tsc' } : {}),
      },
    ],
  ],
  routes: [
    /* Enable an SPA Fallback in development: */
    // {"match": "routes", "src": ".*", "dest": "/index.html"},
  ],
  optimize: {
    /* Example: Bundle your final build: */
    // "bundle": true,
  },
  packageOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  devOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
  buildOptions: {
    /* ... */
  },
};

This is my package.json file
{
  "scripts": {
    "start": "snowpack dev",
    "build": "snowpack build",
    "test": "echo \"This template does not include a test runner by default.\" && exit 1",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{ts,js}\"",
    "lint": "prettier --check \"src/**/*.{ts,js}\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/omggif": "^1.0.5",
    "canvas": "^2.11.2",
    "canvas-confetti": "^1.2.0",
    "etro": "^0.12.1",
    "get-pixels": "^3.3.3",
    "gif-frames": "^1.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@snowpack/plugin-typescript": "^1.2.1",
    "@types/canvas-confetti": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/snowpack-env": "^2.3.3",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "snowpack": "^3.3.7",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  }
}

I'm very new to using typescript and npm. I can provide further information if needed.
I have tried removing packages to see if it works but it isn't working still. I never wrote any piece of code that refers to static/Ethiopia etrojs is the only library I imported in typescript.

Never used this, but the official Snowpack has been unsupported since 20th April, 2022, and doesn't seem to match the given line numbers in the log. There's illogical lines in some places and in at least one case less lines than the log says are in a file. Please edit to include the exact version you're using, including the original repo if it's not the official version.
